# Invoke Generic Method using Action<T>

Tags: c#, delegates

I am creating a generic action to invoke a method from the given generic `<T>`.

```cs
public class TestService
{
    public void TestService1()
    {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

Invoke using this generic method I made in base class

```cs
public abstract class ServiceBase
{
    protected internal void ExecuteService<T>(Action<T> action)
    {
        // execute here
        action.Invoke() // here is my problem
    }
}
```

Executing in other inherited class:

```cs
public void TestVoid()
{
    ExecuteService<TestService>(x => x.TestService1());
}
```

I want to execute invoke `TestService1` method from using the `ExecuteService`.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: Aren't you doing that already? What exactly is wrong with your code?

Comment: @Sweeper, I am trying to execute/invoke the `TestService1` method from ExecuteService using action delegate... how to do this?

Comment: `Action<T>` means a method that takes one parameter of type `T`. However, your method `TestService1` doesn't expect a parameter. So, it's not clear, what you want to achieve

Comment: @NineBerry, I am missing some code in `ExecuteService<T>(Action<T> action)` to invoke execute the method from `TestService1` when I try to execute it didn't went through the contents inside the `TestService1` my question is how to execute the method from the `TestService1`.

Comment: Hi @NineBerry, I updated the question, please check

Comment: TestService1 is not a static method. An instance of TestService would have to be created somewhere. That's not happening anywhere. You have to explain your scenario better. I don't think anyone can understand what you actually want to achieve

Comment: @NineBerry, I tried it using the `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` but I don't know how to extract the method from the action. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is to provide new instance in your action you can simply do it like that:

```
using System;

class Program : ServiceBase
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var program = new Program();

        program.ExecuteService<TestService>(x => x.TestService1());
    }
}

public class TestService
{
    public void TestService1() 
        => Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(TestService)}.{nameof(TestService1)}();");
}

public abstract class ServiceBase
{
    protected internal void ExecuteService<T>(Action<T> action) where T : new() 
        => action?.Invoke(new T());
}
```